# Can't get Metamask account in javascript

Tags: web3js, javascript, metamask

The command:

```
web3.eth.accounts
```

Returns an empty array despite Metamask having one account, how should I be retrieving the accounts in a way that will work with Mist and Metamask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out for Metamask to do or return anything you need to access the dapp through a local or remote webserver and not through the local filesystem (file://) due to browser security restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

The safest way to do it is to call asynchronously, `web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accounts) { })`.

You will also get an empty array if the user is not signed in.

Comment: web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accounts) {
        console.log(accounts);
    })

Comment: Using breakpoints I have deduced that execution never reaches the code within the callback. Any ideas?

Comment: Alternate simple syntax: `web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log)`.

If the code hasn't reached that block, it makes me wonder if the page's connection was broken. Reload the page and try again?

Comment: Turns out for Metamask to do or return anything you need to access the dapp through a local or remote webserver and not through the local filesystem (file://) due to browser security restrictions.

Comment: How can I see the difference between  "account exists and is locked"  and "no account exists" ?

I need to know this to ask the user want to create an account with mascara.

Comment: -> Not now, but later. More here: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/714

Answer (score 2):

I'm also facing same problem. My ganache was running, metamask is also running, web3 is also injected. The problem was `web3.eth.accounts` and `web3.eth.getAccounts().then(...)` was returning null. But after lot of searching I found that

`ethereum.enable()`

I run this command and one metamask popup was opened, which connected my metamask account to app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login in MetaMask
2. Open settings in MetaMask
3. Go to **Connections** and add **localhost** in Add Site and click **Connect**(By doing this you are giving permission to localhost to get access to your MetaMask Account)
4. Now you can get the MetaMask account in your code